# Is there a CSS library for creating website that look like old versions of MacOS?

Tags: macos

Saw https://jdan.github.io/98.css/ which is a CSS library for making interfaces that look like Windows 98.

Is there something similar for old versions of MacOS?

Comment: Good question! Windows 98 is _awfully_ ugly 